# Getting remainder of sequence but with exception on element with remainer zero

Tags: c#, modulus, sequences

Let say i have number 1 to 24, i want to get remainder of these from 12
so with mod 12 sequence would be 1 to 11 and additionally 0 (of 12 and 24) .
But i need this 0 to be always 12. 
How to achieve such a thing in one liner(without additional variables or ifs). 
Right now code is something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i % 12);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneline solution (with slight *overhead* though: `i % 12` could be computed *twice*):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i % 12 == 0 ? 12 : i % 12);
}
```

Pure arithmetic solution is

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(12 - (12 - i % 12) % 12);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking if it can be done through some arithmetics (because of clear pattern of sequence) so we don't have conditionals .

Comment: @rene98c - any other (potential) mathematic solution is just going to be a long winded version of the modulo

Comment: Thanks for arithmetic one Dmitry ;) . I don't know why but i like this more than first one you proposed .

Answer (score 1):

Another arithmetic options:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((i-1) % 12 + 1);
    }
```

This simple makes sure the 'start' is moved one placed to the left (i-1) and corrects the outcome from 0 to 11 to 1 to 12 bij adding 1 to the result

Comment: Looks neat - ended up using this. Seems fairly obvious and this just did'nt come to myself.